# What operations are available in a kubernetes patch?

Tags: kubernetes

`kubectl patch --help` gives an example where you can patch a specific element with a specific operation:

```
kubectl patch pod valid-pod --type='json' \
    -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/containers/0/image",
        "value":"new image"}]'
```

However, there's no enumeration of possible `op` values. What operations are available?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kubectl patch uses [json patch](http://jsonpatch.com) under the hood.
Possible op's are : Replace, Add, Remove

Example:

```
[
  { "op": "replace", "path": "/baz", "value": "boo" },
  { "op": "add", "path": "/hello", "value": ["world"] },
  { "op": "remove", "path": "/foo" }
]
```

Comment: What about [operations](https://jsonpatch.com/#operations) like `copy`, `move`, `test`?